# Listen for any touch gesture in a React Native component

Tags: android, react-native

Given a simple React Native view structure that looks like this:

- TouchableWithoutFeedback (w/ onPress handler)

  - View
  - TouchableHighlight (w/ onPress handler)
  - View

    - View

      - Text
  - TouchableHighlight (w/ onPress handler)

I want to be able to detect all taps at the top level (TouchableWithoutFeedback), even taps that went to one of the TouchableHighlight onPress handlers. It seems like if a user taps on one of the TouchableHighlights, no event propagates to the TouchableWithoutFeedback.

In this simplistic view it would be simple enough to have the TouchableHighlights take a handler that talks to the top level component, but my actual view is too complex and I'd have to make each sub-view pass back tap information.

Based on this issue from the RN Github (https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/6796), it seems like this might not be functionality that is supported, but I just wanted to confirm.

FWIW, I am developing only for Android at the moment.